# import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk

Tags: raspbian, python

I'm with problem with compile this file in Python, I tried to use Python 2 ou 3, but it persist with this error.

When o type `python3.4 ServoMotor.py` it returns me

```
# python3.4 ServoMotor.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ServoMotor.py", line 1, in <module>
 from tkinter import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
   import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
  ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

see below the file `ServoMotor.py`

```
 from tkinter import *
 import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
 import time

 GPIO.setwarnings(0)
 GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
 GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
 pwm = GPIO.PWM(18, 100)
 pwm.start(5)

 class App:

 def __init__(self, master):
     frame = Frame(master)
     frame.pack()
     scale = Scale(frame, from_=0, to=180,orient=HORIZONTAL, command=self.update)
     scale.grid(row=0)

 def update(self, angle):
     duty = float(angle) / 10.0 + 2.5
     pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(duty)


 root = Tk()
 app = App(root)
 root.wm_title('Servo Control')
 root.geometry("200x150+0+0")
 root.mainloop()
```

What can I fix it?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Same question has already been answered on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/543451/configure-tkinter-for-python3-4-2)